# What is the Explanation for DOMDocument's Inconsistent Behavior when Dumping a non-ASCII Character?

Tags: php, html, xml, utf-8, domdocument

I've noticed different "dumping" behaviors when using PHP's `DOMDocument`'s `saveXML()` and `saveHTML()` methods. Here is a simple example of dumping the copyright symbol (©).

`<?
$domDoc = new DOMDocument();

  $domDoc->loadHTML("&copy;");

  echo $domDoc->saveHTML();

  echo $domDoc->saveXML();

  echo $domDoc->saveXML($domDoc);

?>`

The three dumps produce three different outputs:

The first outputs the string `&copy;`
The second outputs the character entity `&#xA9;`
The third outputs the UTF8 2-byte code for the copyright symbol (`U+00A9`)

Why the different outputs? Is there a way to predictability control which method is used?

Comment: Since the primary domain of your question is PHP, you might consider retagging it as such (and dropping one of your other tags)

Comment: Followed your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: +1 I am also wondering why are these inconsistencies between using `loadHtml()`, `loadXml()`, `saveHtml()`, `saveXml()`. Maybe are these bugs in libxml?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a PHP expert, but for the first two:

- saveHTML() will use entities available in HTML, of which `&copy;` is one
- saveXML() will use hex encodings since the HTML entities won't be available

For the third, the documentation says that if you provide a node then the given node is written without an XML declaration (i.e. as a document fragment).  I can only guess that in that case it decides to assume a UTF-8 encoding.  This behavior is not apparent from the documentation.